# Propositional formula which is satisfiable if theres a graph homomorphism?

Tags: graph-theory, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

I was wondering, how could I define a propositional formula $\varphi_{G, H}$, which, given two finite graphs $G$ and $H$, is satisfiable exactly if theres a graph homomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

A graph homomorphism is defined like this:

$h : V(G) \to V (H)$

$\{u, v\} \in E(G) \to  \{h(u), h(v)\} \in E(H)$

Comment: @TheHolyJoker you sure about that? I just need to define a propositional formula that evaluates to 1 <=> theres a gaph homomorphism from two finite graphs G to H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I said in the comment was not precise.

It is unknown, if for every two graphs $G,H$ [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) formula $\varphi_{G,H}$ with polynomial length in $G,H$, such that:
there is some **isomorphism** from $G$ to $H\iff\varphi_{G,H}$ is satisfiable.
This is conjectured to be false.

As for your question, for graph homomorphism, this is possible, since deciding if two graphs are homomorphic, is an NP-Complete problem.

See [Lectures note](https://www.logic.at/lvas/fminf/11S/folien/p/fmi04.pdf) by Reinhard Pichler page 28, for the reduction to $3\text{-SAT}$ problem.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much